# How to put a break in a tcolorbox table?

Tags: page-breaking, tcolorbox, break-box

I am very new to LateX and don't understand the other posts on tcolorbox breaks. It all seems too complicated, I am unable to follow what they do. With pagebreaks it is so easy \pagebreak...

I would like to put a break within the text (as seen below). I want the tcolorbox go from one half of the page (that is why I fixed it with [H]), to the other half of the next page. I don't want it on a whole page, as I need to fill an half-empty page.

And two tcolorboxes wouldn't look nice, as it is supposed to be one text within a box. thanks for the help!

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=white!5,colframe=black!75!black, %arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt, %makes edges sharp 
title= Example title]
%\caption{Example Caption}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{GRAFIC.png}
\end{center}<br />
\begin{flushleft}
\singlespacing<br />
TEXT
**BREAK** (? ) -> easiest way?
TEXT 
\end{flushleft}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can wrap your format your code by selecting it and pressing the `{}` button on the editor so that it becomes easier to read.
Also you should post a MWE (Minimal Working Example), that is a document that begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` containing all the minimum packages and info needed to reproduce the problem, kind of like what you did here :)

Comment: You can take a look at the [tcolorox manual](https://mirrors.chevalier.io/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf) at page 376 for the description of the `breakable` option. You can add it to your `tcolorbox` environement. You can then use the `\tcbbreak` command to break the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      breakable,% allows for the same box to span multiple pages
      colback=white!5,
      colframe=black!75!black,
      ]
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{GRAFIC.png}
      \end{center}
      \begin{flushleft}
        TEXT
        \tcbbreak % this forces the break
        TEXT
      \end{flushleft}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

that resulst in this

[image: compiled file]

I'm not really sure what your end goal is so I don't know if this is what you wanted. Non the less you can easily customize the style to your liking.

If for any chance you wanted onlt the TEXT to be on the new page, while actually seeing the box frame on the first one, you can add the `height fixed for=first` option to your `tcolorbox` environment and obtain

[image: second document]

Comment: thank you so much! it worked! just how can I get the top caption back? I kind of had a thicker frame on top that included a title.

Comment: All good just inserted  ->  title= insert into  [    ]

Comment: Yep, that's it. If you want, you can customize the box to your liking. For example you can have the title on the second box too or you can have different colors and style. Luckily the manual comes with many examples with code so you definitely should find what you want there :)

Comment: maybe I looked into the wrong manual :P but I did not get it when I read it. thanks the code you posted makes sense!+